# Is there some smart way of customizing ajax message text in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have tons of ajax components on this booking engine. I need to customize the text inside of the modal for each of the components to suite.

I added:

```
    $('#loader').bind('ajaxStart', function() {
        $(this).show().addClass('modalOpen');
    }).bind('ajaxComplete', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('modalOpen').hide()
    });
```

Is there some advanced way of changing the text inside of the loading element before I do separate `.ajax` calls? Or do I just have to manually do something like

```
$('#loader').text('blah');
$.ajax({})
```

Furthermore, this may sound silly but is there a way to not have the loader show up for certain components? If not I imagine I'll have to do something like

```
$('someel').someEvent(function() {
    $('#loader').addClass('override-hide');
    $.ajax({
       success:function() {
          $('#loader').removeClass('override-hide');
       }
    })
})

#loader.override-hide { display:none !important; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the `beforeSend` callback for both of your examples:

```
$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function() {
      $('#loader').text('Message for this call').show();
   },
   success:function() {
      $('#loader').hide();
   }
});
```

Just leave out `.show()`/`.hide()` or `.text()` if you don't want it shown or the message changed, whatever you want in each case.

[See a full list of events here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @Nick Craver you probably meant `$('#loader').text('Message for this call').show();` +1